# Updating value of EFCircularSlider to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using a library called EFCircularSlider. It is an `ObjC` library and I have successfully imported it in my project. The issue is however i am not able to update the slider value to a `UILabel`.

```
let sliderFrame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 200, 200)
let circularSlider = EFCircularSlider(frame: sliderFrame)

 circularSlider.addTarget(self,
                          action:#selector(TemperatureConversion.valueChange(_:)),
                          forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged
 )

 self.view.addSubview(circularSlider)

 func valueChange(sender: EFCircularSlider){
    circularSlider.minimumValue = 0
    circularSlider.maximumValue = 100
    circularSlider.currentValue = 0


    upperLabel.text = "\(circularSlider.currentValue)"

}
```

[image]

This is how it is done in ObjC. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this line inside `viewDidLoad` method instead of `valueChange` method. So add this line in `viewDidLoad` and change your `valueChange` like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let sliderFrame = CGRectMake(100, 150, 200, 200)
    let circularSlider = EFCircularSlider(frame: sliderFrame)
    circularSlider.addTarget(self,action:#selector(TemperatureConversion.valueChange(_:)),
                      forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    circularSlider.minimumValue = 0
    circularSlider.maximumValue = 100
    circularSlider.currentValue = 0
    self.view.addSubview(circularSlider)
}

func valueChange(sender: EFCircularSlider){
    upperLabel.text = "\(sender.currentValue)"
}
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome mate:) Happy Coding:)

Comment: The issue was you are setting `currentValue` to again 0 inside the `valueChange` method.

Comment: This library EFCircularSlider is a bit buggy. The slider does not stop once 360 degree rotation is completed, kind of like endless cycle.

Comment: I have never used this `EFCircularSlider`, so no idea mate, Put the new question may be that will help you.